# How to use MultithreadedTC to test multithreading application?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, testing

I am struggling to use multithreadedTC to test my multithreading application. The website provides some examples (http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/multithreadedtc/overview.html#examples2to4), but all the examples are testing against multithreading constructs (e.g. AtomicInteger, Semaphore) as oppose to methods which uses multithreading constructs.

Now I have a simple content fetcher. How to test against "fetch()" method using multithreadedTC?

```
    public class ConcurrentFetcher {

    private URL[] urls = new URL[3];

    public ConcurrentFetcher() throws MalformedURLException {
        urls[0] = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
        urls[1] = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        urls[2] = new URL("http://www.bing.com");
    }

    private void fetch() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>();

        for (final URL url : urls) {
            tasks.add(new Callable<String>() {

                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

                    String line;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
                }
            });
        }

        List<Future<String>> promises = es.invokeAll(tasks, 10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        for (Future promise : promises) {
            System.out.println(promise.get());
        }

        es.shutdown();
    }

    public static void main(
            String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        ConcurrentFetcher fetcher = new ConcurrentFetcher();
        fetcher.fetch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `sb.append(line)` is discarding new lines.  A better/faster way to read text is to read a `char[]` and copy this into a StringBuilder.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik What do you use for testing multithreaded method then?

Comment: You can check out [jcstress](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jcstress/). It's what the HotSpot team uses to test a new Java edition before releasing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I checked out jcstress, but this tool is only for 1.8. 

Detected JDK Version: 1.7.0-21 is not in the allowed range 1.8.